# How do you click on this deeply nested class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I access the class I marked blue on the screenshot below and click on it?
The "main class" and "section class" always got the same name. I have tried by starting at a class which I believe is the parent and find about its children step by step by using

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("_9eogI E3X2T")[0];
window.alert(x);
```

but that keeps giving me "undefined" and I don't know how to get into the class I marked on the screenshot because the blue marked area in code always got a different name too :/

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "access and click on it"? What is the problem you're trying to solve with this solution?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByClassName("v1Nh3")[0].click();`?

Comment: Also the classes you're using do not match the element you're selecting?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The blue marked area in html it resembles a picture and I like to click on this picture

Comment: @jabaa Yes this gives me the output: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: A click shouldn't give you an output. It should simulate a mouse button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `let x = document.querySelector('.Nnq7C.weEfm');`

*querySelector* will return the first element matching the query. Keep in mind that you have to add the "." to specify that you want to query a class. Also if you want to query for elements with multiple classes on them, you have to write it as one string without spaces and every class should start with a ".".